# How can I leave Hong Kong when I've lost my landing slip (Departure card)?

Tags: paperwork, hong-kong

I'm currently in Mainland China and in one week plan to leave for Hong Kong to depart to Canada. I just noticed that I cannot find my landing slip and possibly lost it.

Is there anything I can do?
I cannot leave HK without presenting the landing slip, can I?

Comment: I would note that if you are in mainland China you already left Hong Kong. You should get a new slip when you reenter Hong Kong.

Comment: Are we talking about your yellow arrival card that you got upon entering China?

Comment: Why has this question got 3 close votes as "unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: @Blaszard Because he's not in HK but his question is how to leave.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear (again) because it is not clear whether the OP is referring to his HK landing slip or a Chinese arrival card and because the Q is about leaving HK while currently in China, which is unclear until further specified.

Answer (score 10):

See answer below from the [Hong Kong Immigration Department](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/useful_information/non-stamping-immigration-clearance.html). You can easily get a replacement although it appears you do not require it to clear departure formalities.

> Q3: Is it necessary for a non-permanent resident to apply for a
>   replacement of landing slip in case of loss and where to apply?
>
> A3: The landing slip bears a non-permanent resident’s conditions and
>   limit of stay. He/she should keep the landing slip while remaining in
>   Hong Kong. **Under normal circumstances, loss of landing slip will
>   not affect the departure clearance formalities.** Those who require a
>   replacement of the landing slip may apply for free at the Extension
>   Section (5/F, Immigration Tower, 7 Gloucester Road, Wanchai, Hong
>   Kong).

Comment: Totally true from experience . I am in and out of HK at least twice a month. No problem without the Slip. Also, twice I did get a replacement slip - but that was at the border itself in immigration ( just go to the main office and ask for it if you have a good reason for needing one )

Answer (score 1):

In theory, nothing will block you from departure, although you should apply for a replacement in principle. In practice, there is absolute no need to apply for a replacement anyway. I never intentionally keep my landing slips for Hong Kong, and there was not a single time which the immigration officer actually cared about it. The landing slip is mainly for your reference so that you don't overstay.