# What to do in case of lost landing card in UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

I think I lost my landing card after clearing the UK border. Other questions like this [one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87914/how-can-i-leave-hong-kong-when-ive-lost-my-landing-slip-departure-card) from Hong Kong (there are also other examples) suggests that it is not required to clear departure formalities.

Can someone please tell me if this is also true for UK? 
Will I get in trouble or go through some red tape related to the issue?

I'm thinking this must be a very commonplace occurence.

Comment: It's so commonplace, it happens to everyone who passes immigration :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't keep the landing card; the officer collects it and usually discards it, except if wanting to keep you on record, in which case it's kept by the officer.

> that it is not required to clear departure formalities.

There are no departure formalities in the UK - you clear security and that's it