# Will I receive a second HK landing slip on rentry or do I keep the first one?

Tags: hong-kong, macau

if I were to do a day trip from HK to Macau by bus, do they take the first landing slip off me? Or do they give another one to me on the way back into Hong Kong? Thanks.

Comment: The last few times I left Hong Kong (by plane) they just told me to throw the landing slip away. No one wanted to see it.

Comment: No one will demand to see your landing slip, really, but yes you'll get a second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will receive a new one.** In any case the landing slip is only for your own reference, it will not be checked or collected.

See also: [How can I leave Hong Kong when I've lost my landing slip (Departure card)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87914/how-can-i-leave-hong-kong-when-ive-lost-my-landing-slip-departure-card)